fmt_currency() from gt package renders currency name and not currency symbol when knit to pdf in Rmarkdown
so I am using gt() and then fmt_currency() to add the £ symbol in one of my tables.
On Rstudio it works fine, but then when knit to pdf I see GBP in front of the numbers instead of the symbol.
Is anyone aware of potential restrictions of the function fmt_currency() when its output is exported in pdf? so it only works for html type of files?
Or is there an option with Rmarkdown for the output to use the symbol rather than the name?
enter image description here
enter image description here
Happy to provide the code if needed but it is quite straitforward:
mydataset %>% gt() %>% fmt_currency(currency="GBP")

The Rmarkdown I am using is not customized beyond the default option for kniting at the beginning.
I tried to look online for specifications regarding fmt_currency() but could not find any noted constraints regarding output.
When I knit the same Rmarkdown to html the symbol is displayed correctly.
My gut feeling is that I'll have to make specification on the Rmarkdown to have the output I want, but I am not sure where to look. Any advice?

You could try to supply a custom currency symbol to fmt_currency()
  fmt_currency(
    columns = currency,
    currency = currency(
      latex =  "£"
    )
  )

MWE:
---
format: pdf
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
exibble |>
  dplyr::select(currency) |>
  gt() |>
  fmt_currency(
    columns = currency,
    currency = currency(
      latex =  "£"
    )
  )
```


